# Cloud Redis latency causes (vs. local redis on macbook pro)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, cloud, heroku-redis

Redis can give sub millisecond response times. That's a great promise. I'm testing heroku redis and I get `1ms` up to about `8ms`, for a `zincrby`. I'm using `microtime()` in php to wrap the call. This heroku redis (I'm using the free plan) is a shared instance and there is resource contention so I expect response times for identical queries to vary, and they certainly do.

I'm curious as to the cause of the difference in performance vs. redis installed on my macbook pro via homebrew. There's obviously no network latency there. What I'm curious about is does this mean that any cloud redis (i.e. connecting over the network, say within aws), is always going to be quite a bit slower than if I were to have one cloud server and run a redis inside the same physical machine, thus eliminating network latency?

There is also resource contention in these cloud offerings, unless a private server is chosen which costs a lot more.

Some numbers: my local macbook pro consistently gives `0.2ms` for the identical `zincrby` that takes between `1ms` & `8ms` on the heroku redis.

Is network latency the cause of this?

Comment: For interest, inter-region latency appears always > 10ms: https://www.cloudping.co/

Comment: I would have expected low latency for redis in the same vpc as the instance. Are you testing on-prem + cloud redis, or cloud-instance + cloud-redis?

Comment: @MatthewArthur  It's cloud-instance & cloud-redis.  But not, of course, as containers running on the same piece of hardware. These are containers running within the same aws region, I think that's all we can know. So it's intra-region latency that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, probably not.

The typical latency of a 1 Gbit/s network is about `200us`.  That's `0.2ms`.

What's more, in aws you're probably on 10gbps at least.

As [this page](https://redis.io/topics/latency) in the redis manual explains, the main cause of the latency variation between these two environments will almost certainly be a result of the higher `intrinsic latency` (there's a redis command to test this on any particular system: `redis-cli --intrinsic-latency 100`, see the manual page above) **arising from being run in a linux container**.

i.e., network latency is not the dominant cause of the variation seen here.

Here is a checklist  (from redis manual page linked above).

> - If you can afford it, prefer a physical machine over a VM to host the server.
> - Do not systematically connect/disconnect to the server (especially true for web based applications). Keep your connections as long lived
>     as possible.
> - If your client is on the same host than the server, use Unix domain sockets.
> - Prefer to use aggregated commands (MSET/MGET), or commands with variadic parameters (if possible) over pipelining.
> - Prefer to use pipelining (if possible) over sequence of roundtrips.
> - Redis supports Lua server-side scripting to cover cases that are not suitable for raw pipelining (for instance when the result of a command
>     is an input for the following commands).

Comment: Something told me aws internal networks were unlikely to be a significant bottleneck... - if they were, they'd be on the case & would have fixed it  :)